# For a continuous rotation representation in 3D, do you need at least 4 real variables?

Tags: 3d

I'm pretty sure I have read this somewhere, but I just can't get to find this theorem anywhere.

Is there a theorem that states that for a continuous rotation representation you need at least 4 real variables?

Comment: The intuition  that shows you don't need more than three variables is: a rotation in 3d is defined by an axis, and an amount of rotation around the axis.  The axis itself is determined by specifying a single point on the unit sphere, so requires at most a latitude and a longitude, two variables.  The amount of rotation is of course at most one variable; that makes no more than three.

Comment: [Related Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/123hyat/to_create_a_continuous_rotation_representation_in/)

Comment: Thanks for your input! I was mostly interested in finding the explanation of why 3 variables, even though they are enough, are not perfectly continuous and without singularities on the whole domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I found what I was looking for! Instead of putting the explanation, I'll rather leave the paper where I found my answer:

[John Stuelpnagel - On the Parametrization of the Three-Dimensional Rotation Group, 1964](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1006093)

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to come back and answer your own question.